# If condition is true even then else is executing

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, enums, static-methods

I have an `enum` defined as below, which contains a static function `fromString(String s)` which is like `valueOf(String s)` but case insensitive.

```
enum Platform {
    TWITTER("TWITTER"), INSTAGRAM("INSTAGRAM"), UNKNOWN;

    private String value;

    Platform(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final Map<String, Platform> stringToEnumMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (Platform platform : values()) {
            stringToEnumMap.put(platform.toString().toLowerCase(), platform);
        }
    }

    public static Platform fromString(String symbol) {
        Platform platform = stringToEnumMap.get(symbol.toLowerCase());
        if (platform != null) {
            return platform;
        } else {
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getValue();
    }

}
```

but when I execute the following code

```
Platform platform = Platform.fromString("twitter");
```

I get `Platform.UNKNOWN` returned on few devices on production.

Any Idea?

**Update**

`symbol.toString()` gives `twitter`

`stringToEnumMap.toString()` gives this

> Platform StringToEnumMap: {
>   twıtter=TWITTER, ınstagram=INSTAGRAM, 
>   unknown=UNKNOWN}

If you look closely, the letter `i` is different in the keys of HashMap and thats why string comparison fails.

the hexvalue of letter `ı` in `stringToEnumMap` is 0131, whereas the it should be 0069

Why is this happening on only few devices? How to avoid it?

Comment: Possibly you are not debugging the code you think you are. Are you sure your IDE is recompiling the code before the debugger is run?

Comment: Hum, if your debugger is telling you that the `if` is`true`... then either you're not looking at the right code, you didn't recompile, or both...

Comment: The code works for me. Can you post a MVCE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Try without an IDE, just `javac` and `java` on the shell.

Comment: Maybe android studio is using a old version of your code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey updated the que. I rebuilt my code but still the same.

Comment: @Robert I believe I have provided a MVCE code only as the actually code is very different. The only problem is that it is only reproducible on Android Studio I believe.

Comment: So it steps into the return `letter` but `letter` is UNKNOWN after you return. I would try change the code e.g. rename UNKNOWN, or remove it to see what happens.

Comment: Don't complicate your code with a `Map`. It's just code bloat. Simply iterate through `values` in your `fromString` looking for a case-insensitive match.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the `Map` through the debugger?

Comment: @LewBloch yeah I did.

Comment: Everyone, sorry for being away but I was adding some logs to understand what was happening. Now I have even more insight why this happens. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find what the issue was. After some careful logging I found the issue was this http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug.

Apparently `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` functions are locale dependent due to which you can't use them safely for case insensitive string comparison. 
So all you need to do is pass the english locale in the parameter of these functions like this -

`toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a dirty ide issue, try to clean up your project, build and run again.

**UPDATE**
Try replacing your if statement by getOrDefault method:

```
public static Letter fromString(String symbol) {
    return stringToEnumMap.getOrDefault(symbol.toLowerCase(), UNKNOWN);
}
```

Comment: I am using Android Studio. I am rebuilding the code and then will try again.

Comment: Updated the question. I rebuilt my code but still the same.

Comment: `getOrDefault()` function is only available in API 24 and above. But it did worked here. I am thinking of copy pasting the code inside it.

Comment: Everyone, sorry for being away but I was adding some logs to understand what was happening. Now I have even more insight why this happens. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my Opinion, there is no need for a map.... nor a new method for doing something that **valueOf()** is able to do...

look this implemetation..

```
enum ECase {
    A, B, UNK;

    public static ECase resolveEnumFromString(final String string) {
        ECase r = null;
        try {
            r = ECase.valueOf(string.toUpperCase());
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            r = ECase.UNK;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

you can verify the results doing:

```
    ECase d = null;
    d = ECase.resolveEnumFromString("a");
    System.out.println(d);
    d = ECase.resolveEnumFromString("A");
    System.out.println(d);
    d = ECase.resolveEnumFromString("0");
    System.out.println(d);
```